# How to get list of Channel administrators from the Telegram API?

Tags: telegram

Most of the information I have found relating to this refers to the Bot Api. The only way I can see to get the information from the full API is by using GetParticipants, however, that requires that the requesting user be an admin.

Comment: please explain more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For get a list of administrators (except other bots) in a channel, you can use the [getChatAdministrators](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatadministrators) method.

Remember that the bot **must be admin** of the channel. *In no way you can get the administrators of a channel without be an administrator.*

Comment: I can’t fully understand that , can you please provide a quote example, in python or JavaScript?